# php - allow negative decimal using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, currency

I have input mask in a variable like this `200.000,54`

This is my php code

```
<?php

class MoneyHelper
{
    public function getAmount($money)
    {
        $cleanString = preg_replace('/([^0-9\.,])/i', '', $money);
        $onlyNumbersString = preg_replace('/([^0-9])/i', '', $money);

        $separatorsCountToBeErased = strlen($cleanString) - strlen($onlyNumbersString) - 1;

        $stringWithCommaOrDot = preg_replace('/([,\.])/', '', $cleanString, $separatorsCountToBeErased);
        $removedThousandSeparator = preg_replace('/(\.|,)(?=[0-9]{3,}$)/', '',  $stringWithCommaOrDot);

        //return (float) str_replace(',', '.', $removedThousandSeparator);

        return [
          'cleanString' => $cleanString,
          'onlyNumbersString' => $onlyNumbersString,
          'separatorsCountToBeErased' => $separatorsCountToBeErased,
          'stringWithCommaOrDot' => $stringWithCommaOrDot,
          'removedThousandSeparator' => $removedThousandSeparator,
          'result' => (float) str_replace(',', '.', $removedThousandSeparator)

        ];

    }
}


$obj = new MoneyHelper;
echo var_dump($obj->getAmount('200.000,54')) ;
```

The result is:

```
array (size=6)
 'cleanString' => string '200.000,54' (length=10)
 'onlyNumbersString' => string '20000054' (length=8)
 'separatorsCountToBeErased' => int 1
 'stringWithCommaOrDot' => string '200000,54' (length=9)
 'removedThousandSeparator' => string '200000,54' (length=9)
 'result' => float 200000.54
```

Everything is fine until I test this code with negative number.
Let's say `- 200.000,54`

Then result is still same,

```
array (size=6)
  'cleanString' => string '200.000,54' (length=10)
  'onlyNumbersString' => string '20000054' (length=8)
  'separatorsCountToBeErased' => int 1
  'stringWithCommaOrDot' => string '200000,54' (length=9)
  'removedThousandSeparator' => string '200000,54' (length=9)
  'result' => float 200000.54
```

How can I get the negative number in result?
Please advise ...

**Update**

> You haven't told us your exact desired output

I need: `'result' => float -200000.54`

Comment: Decimal is `/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/` or `/^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/`  Optional `-` then a number, then optionally a `.` and some more numbers.  The `^` start and `$` end insure you don't partial match such as `123foo`

Comment: As for the problem, your stripping it 2x at least right here `preg_replace('/([^0-9\.,])/i'`  No minus in there, so it's removed and another time on the following line.

Comment: `.` doesn't need to be escaped in a character class.

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the negative symbols to your negated character classes.  I may a few other adjustments too.

Snippet: ([Full Demo](https://3v4l.org/bTW84))

```
$cleanString = preg_replace('/[^\d.,-]/', '', $money);
$onlyNumbersString = preg_replace('/[^\d-]/', '', $money);

$separatorsCountToBeErased = strlen($cleanString) - strlen($onlyNumbersString) - 1;

$stringWithCommaOrDot = preg_replace('/[,.]/', '', $cleanString, $separatorsCountToBeErased);
$removedThousandSeparator = preg_replace('/[.,](?=\d{3,}$)/', '',  $stringWithCommaOrDot);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  ["cleanString"]=>
  string(11) "-200.000,54"
  ["onlyNumbersString"]=>
  string(9) "-20000054"
  ["separatorsCountToBeErased"]=>
  int(1)
  ["stringWithCommaOrDot"]=>
  string(10) "-200000,54"
  ["removedThousandSeparator"]=>
  string(10) "-200000,54"
  ["result"]=>
  float(-200000.54)
}
```